# Javascript in Google Sheets script: help using setNumberFormat

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

Hoping this is a simple problem for you lot. I have no coding knowledge at all. But been using the below script in a Google Sheet to grab changing data from another sheet and log it daily, appending as it goes. Can't remember where I found the script - if I did I'd go back and ask its creator. It's been working fine; only thing is I have to manually copy paste my preferred date format every day. So I'd like the script to print the date in "dd/MM/yyyy" format (while retaining hours and minutes data inside the cell). I've been reading and searching online, and experimenting for ages but can't figure it out. This is the base code:

```
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
  var source = sheet.getRange("A2:C2");
  var values = source.getValues();
  values[0][0] = new Date();
  sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
};
```

I've tried placing `setnumberformat` in various places and nearly always get an error. Perhaps my best attempt, inspired by other examples I've seen, was to add these new lines:

```
function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("History");
  var source = sheet.getRange("A2:C2");
  var values = source.getValues();
  values[0][0] = new Date();
  sheet.appendRow(values[0]);
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(2, 1, 979);
  cell.setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
};
```

I hoped this would format the entire date row (Row A) after appending the new data. Probably a clunky solution even if it worked, but it didn't. It's my only attempt so far that doesn't return an error! So, yay? But it doesn't change the date format. So I give up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To specify the format for a specific cell

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("A2");
cell.setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

To specify the format for a range of cells

```
var cells = sheet.getRange("A2:C2");
cells.setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Please see the documentation for [Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setNumberFormats(Object)) and [formats](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/formats).

Comment: Perfect! I was so close too. Clearly misunderstood the documentation advice for getRange. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Glad to be of help. Please be so kind to accept my answer to put the question to resolved for future readers. :)

Comment: I'm assuming that's the green tick beneath the up/down vote. And if so, done. Thanks also for the meta tip :)

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you need the time as well, follow this code.

```
var cell = sheet.getRange("A2");
cell.setNumberFormat("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm:ss AM/PM");
```