# Google sheets script date format

Tags: javascript, function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have no coding knowledge so I really need help.

I have a scheduled report thats sent to my email everyday with updates, I have used a Google sheet script that goes to my email and exports this report into the sheet but the column with the dates (B2:B1551) are formated this way: 1st Jul 19 ect, I need it to be converted into dd/mm/yyyy format without doing it manually. Is it possible to create a script that converts column B or a new column that reads column B and converts it into a dd/mm/yyyy format?

Comment: Yes - it's possible. Have you tried anything yourself to accomplish this?

Comment: Mind sharing your work with us? We love to help however we are not a code writing service.

Comment: I have tried this but to no avail
 function recordHistory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var source = sheet.getRange("B2:B1551");
  var values = source.getValues();
  // Cell B2 contains a date
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2");
cell.setNumberFormat('dd-mm-yyyy');

};

Comment: @GentleSama It wont let me copy the code into my post but I have used this code here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705906/javascript-in-google-sheets-script-help-using-setnumberformat

Comment: Regarding the script you tried - what was the outcome? Did it format the dates at all?

Comment: Hi @ross nothing worked for me lol the format of column B is still something like 1st Jul 19 instead of dd/mm/yyyy format. I would appreciate any insight anyone has as I am unsure what to do.

Comment: Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet, remove any confidential or private information. And include in the spreadsheet an example of how a successful outcome would/should appear. Would you please also edit your question to include the code that you have tried; it's very hard to find when its in the comments only.

Comment: @Nsaid Also include your script that copies the data across - we could just incorporate the date format in that script instead if possible.

Comment: @ross here is a spreadsheet with dates along with the format I want: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-LB8bcHEilRmGgF2-4xG-wg_lRi6VH8TXMogfYfl8uE/edit#gid=0 . The script can be found in TOOLS > Script editor

Comment: @Tedinoz The copy of the spreadsheet can be found here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-LB8bcHEilRmGgF2-4xG-wg_lRi6VH8TXMogfYfl8uE/edit#gid=0

Comment: Thank you guys!! truly appreciate it

Comment: @Nsaid Next time, please include the script in your question. It's one of the things you'll see in the Help section about writing a good question. The reason is that everyone reading your question can also look at your script. But if you leave it to us to find your script in your spreadsheet, then many people who might possibly have been able to help will be justifiably put off by the extra time and effort.

Comment: @Tedinoz, I completely understand I wanted to include the script in the post but it kept showing an error. Its my  first time using the site so apologies! I will include it for next time

Comment: No worries. And I'm glad you seem to have an answer to your problem. Success all round, eh! FWIW, if the @ross answer resolves your problem, you might consider accepting it.

Answer (score 3):

#### Code:

Your current code uses this to set the first array object to a timestamp:

```
values[0][0] = new Date();
```

---

#### Solution:

We can use [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String)) to format this date, here's the syntax:

```
Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format);
```

So the new, updated code would look something like this:

```
values[0][0] = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+0", "dd/MM/yyyy");
```

---

#### References:

- [`Utilities.formatDate()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))
- [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)