# Get time format according to spreadsheet locale?

Tags: datetime, google-apps-script, google-sheets, locale, number-formatting

I want to store a Javascript `Date()` object in a spreadsheet with correct format according to spreadsheet's locale (`SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetLocale()`).
Is there a way to get the country specific (date and) time format string from the spreadsheet locale?
E.g. when locale is de_DE, time format string as `hh:mm`
but when locale is da_DK, time format string as `hh.mm`
Interesting as well how to get the countries currency format.

BTW when I have date and time in `de_DE` and than change to `da_DK`, dates are reformatted `(23.01.2020 -> 23/01/2020`) but times are not (it stays as `22:59`). Is that an error in Spreadsheet?

Answer (score 2):

Dates in JavaScript have the method [toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), which return a string formatted according to the specified locale. But this doesn't seem to work in Apps Script.

If you're open to using an [Apps Script Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) for this, you could use this `toLocaleDateString` in your client-side script (that is, in a script tag in your HTML).

If that's not the case, I think your best option would be to create the relationship between formats and locales yourself, because Apps Script doesn't have a built-in method to achieve that. You could, for example, use a [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement that would check the locale, and then format the date accordingly with [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format), the tool Apps Script uses to format dates. It could be something along the following lines:

```js
var locale = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetLocale();
var formattedDate;
switch (locale) {
  case 'de_DE':
    formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(yourDate, yourTimeZone, "hh:mm");
    break;
  case 'da_DK':
    formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(yourDate, yourTimeZone, "hh.mm");
    break;
    // ...
}
return formattedDate;
```

#### Reference:

- [toLocateDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)
- [Apps Script Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)
- [Utilities.formatDate](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

I hope this is of any help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for that, however I found a function that would be worth checking out, it's toLocaleDateString() and toLocaleTimeString (), they deliver the local date and time format.
Please check
[Formato fechas JavaScript](https://www.aprenderaprogramar.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=846:formato-fechas-javascript-tostring-tolocaledatestring-tolocaletimestrig-totimestring-ejemplo-cu01163e&catid=78&Itemid=206).

I did the test from Google Apps Script and it throws me the following

```
function pruebafecha() {
  var d = new Date();
  var n = d.toLocaleDateString();
  var h = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  Logger.log(n);
  Logger.log(h);
}

This is the answer(Colombia): 
[20-01-24 16:47:50:286 EST] 24 de enero de 2020
[20-01-24 16:47:50:287 EST] 16:47:50 EST
```

Comment: toLocaleTimeString() does not care about the locale set fro the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

A JavaScript Date object includes date, time and timezone. When Google Apps Script pass a Date object to the spreadsheet using `setValue()` / `setValues()` the value is displayed according to the cell number formatting using the spreadsheet timezone.

If the cell formatting is set to Automatic by default the date will be displayed accordingly to the spreadsheet locale.

If you want to force the cell to display a date in an specific format use Class Range [setNumberFormat](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat) / [setNumberFormats](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatsnumberformats)

If you don't want to use the above methods and don't want to rely on the spreadsheet locale and automatic cell format then instead of passing a Date object pass the value as an string prepending it with an `'` (apostrophe, single quote character) to prevent that that automatic data type parsing changes the value and it's format.

Related

[Javascript in Google Sheets script: help using setNumberFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48705906/1595451)

Comment: When I pass a Date object, the cell is showing the date, not the time. But I want the time to show (hours and minutes, no seconds), not the date. I search for a way to avoid `setNumberFormat(...)` since the format string is locale dependent, or a way to retrieve that format string according to spreadsheet's locale setting.

Comment: "But I want the time to show.. not the date" The question doesn't say that so you might edit the question or to post  new one.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know very well the configuration of the sheet you mention. However, I share a code that I use to print the date and time of data submission of a form.

```
var d = new Date();
var hour = d.getHours()-1;
var min = d.getMinutes();
var day = d.getDate();
var month = d.getMonth()+1;
var year = d.getFullYear();

if (month<10) {dia = day+"/"+"0"+month+"/"+year;}
 else {dia = day+"/"+month+"/"+year;}
 if (min<10){time = hour+":"+"0"+min;}
 else {time = hour+":"+min;}
```

What I do in the code is to take the values ​​of day, month and year, I add 1 to the value of month because it takes values ​​[0:11] => [Jan, Dec].
Then I build the format I want from date and time, you can notice that I have 1 left to the hours, because when I did the tests I noticed that the time of the script was one hour above.

I use google translate, I hope it is understood.

Comment: Google translate is very good. But my question was about the date and time "format". In your locale, "/" is the delimiter between parts of date and ":" is delimiter between parts of time. In danish locale, "/" is date delimiter and "." is time delimiter. In german locale, "." is date delimiter and ":" is time delimiter. I'm searching for a way to find out the delimiter character per locale.