# Date Format from Google Sheets to HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have the date as follows in Google Sheets

[image]

Now I use the below code to get the date and sent to Mail

```
function(){
const rs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const ws = rs.getSheetByName("Page1");
const dateval=ws.getRange("C2").getValue();
const htmlTemplate=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlsend");
htmlTemplate.dateval=dateval;
}
```

When I call the `dateval` to HTML and when I send to Mail, I get the output of date as **Fri Sep 17 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)** instead of **17-09-2021**

Help me to convert the date format to **17-09-2021** as like

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript in Google Sheets script: help using setNumberFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705906/javascript-in-google-sheets-script-help-using-setnumberformat)

Comment: I got answer, I used const dateval=ws.getRange("C2").getDisplayValue(); instead of getValue();

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way:

```
function(){
  const rs = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const ws = rs.getSheetByName("Page1");
  const dateval=ws.getRange("C2").getValue();
  const htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("htmlsend");

  htmlTemplate.dateval = Utilities.formatDate(dateval, 'America/Sao_Paulo', 'dd-MM-yyyy');
}
```

Where "America/Sao_Paulo" is the code of the timeZone.